# How can you tell the difference between a male or female banjo catfish?

Tags: fish, freshwater, gender-differentiation

I recently added two banjo catfish to my tank, and just out of curiosity, I was wondering how I would determine the sex of them?

Answer (score 1):

[Animal-world.com](http://animal-world.com/encyclo/fresh/catfish/banjocat.php) says that while the two sexes look similar, the mature female has a "fuller and rounder belly."

[Aqualandpetsplus.com](http://aqualandpetsplus.com/Catfish,%20Banjo.htm) adds that the a fully-grown female may be larger in general.